# php improper comparison behavior

Tags: php, string, string-comparison, string-length

```
$string = '540';

if (strlen ($string >= 34)){
    print_r((substr($string, 0, 30) . "..."));
} else {
    print_r(($string));
}
```

If `$string` is longer than 34 characters it should be appended with a "...", otherwise it should just print the string.

I think what's happening is that the interpreter is assuming the string is a number when it does the comparison.

It also has the same hiccup if I change `$string` to

```
$string = '540 rocks !'
```

Why is this?

Comment: What made you think that `>` compares *the number of digits*???

Comment: Also, you don't ever need double parentheses, so change your `print_r(($string))` to `print_r($string)`.

Comment: My bad. . . I was rushing, didn't notice the parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
if (strlen($string) >= 34)) {
```

Not

```
if ($string >= 34)){
```

Answer (score 2):

If the test you want to do is on the string length, just change this line:

```
if ($string >= 34)){
```

into this:

```
if (strlen($string) >= 34)){
```